# How to batch export .tif and .shp from TNTmips RVC folders?

Tags: shapefile, geotiff-tiff, batch, tntmips

We have approximately 600 RVC folders per year, for a 30 year period (repeated visit of plots), that contain both georeferenced aerial images and vector mapping of wet areas via heads up digitizing. We are hoping to develop a SML script that can help us batch export these data to .tif and .shp files. Something like, for every year list RVC, for ever RVC list raster/vector, for every raster/vector export to folder as .tif and .shp. Any help developing an SML script would be a huge contribution towards our effort to archive legacy data for public consumption. Frankly there has been a replacement of staff that have more skills in AcrGIS/python than TNTmips/SML and we would like to make sure legacy data are stored in a format that is more sustainable.